# Can you be electrocuted while taking a shower during a thunderstorm?

Tags: electromagnetism

I remember growing up and my mom always telling me to not take a shower while it was thunderstorming. I've done it a few times but I always try to keep the water not flowing over my body in case it ever did happen it wouldn't cross my heart and kill me.

So, can you be electrocuted while taking a shower during a thunderstorm?

Comment: Hardly a good citation, but fun - [Annotated Mythbusters, Episode 30: Son of a Gun, Showering during a Thunderstorm](http://kwc.org/mythbusters/2005/03/mythbusters_son_of_a_gun_showe.html)

Comment: You still would need to touch two different electrical potentials, e.g. the metallic shower head and the drain. However, in any good installation these parts are all electrical connected to each other and should be grounded. This doesn't leave much current to flow through you. So IMHO theoretical possible but unlikely. Almost impossible with a correctly build modern house (lighting rod on the roof, grounding plumbing, etc.).

Comment: @Martin: Water is also a quite good conductor (unless it's chemically 100% pure). Tap water will never be so pure that it does not lead electricity.

Comment: @awe: I know, but I don't think it will ever conduct as well as grounding wire. Like I said, it is possible but unlikely. It's also not so that the lighting will more likely hit your house just because you have a shower. It's much more likely to get hit by a car once you left the house. Did you mom also told you not to leave the house?

Comment: @Martin: Lightning is not too picky about the quality of the conductor... And unclean water is actually a quite good conductor if you compare to other non-metal materials. If the lightening strike in the ground and hits the plumbing (as in [this article](http://www.kcci.com/r/16265120/detail.html) referenced by [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/can-you-be-electrocuted-while-taking-a-shower-during-a-thunderstorm/3789#3789)), the water will be the best choice for the lightning to travel once it comes out of the shower.

Comment: @awe: Yes indeed, the water, not your body. See Tjarrt's comment below manojlds answer. It might happen, and normally people can wait until the storm passes before they shower, but I personally wouldn't be scared. The chances that your house is hit, your lightning rod fails (In Germany we have lighting rods on every house), the current really goes through your shower and not any other possible way (there is a lot of plumbing in a house and all holds normally water) etc. is so low that it is nothing to worry about. Sure it happened in the history of mankind, almost everything does..

Comment: @Martin: I imagine that it is entirely possible, though like most of you said it is highly unlikely. Overhere in the US most people don't have lightning rods, so the chance of a house being hit is more likely unless it has a television antenna or something similar to that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at this document talking about lightning myths - http://newweb.wrh.noaa.gov/hnx/LightningMyths-1.pdf

> You must avoid any conducting path
>   leading outside, such as corded
>   telephones, electrical appliances,
>   wires, TV cables, plumbing (including
>   plastic pipes with water in them),
>   metal doors or window frames, etc.

Also from here: http://indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/can-lightning-strike-you-in-the-shower/

> Metal is a good conductor, so if
>   lightning strikes an unprotected
>   house, chances are the current will
>   travel through any metal pipes. What’s
>   more, the tap water moving in these
>   pipes contains impurities that help
>   the water conduct electrical current.
>
> When you’re wet, the natural
>   resistance of your body is cut by
>   half, and the salt and contaminants on
>   your skin decrease your resistance
>   further. So basically, being wet can
>   make the difference between an
>   unpleasant electrical shock and a
>   deadly one.

Comment: Sooo, in other words yes it can kill you?

Comment: A few years back I saw a program on discovery channel about people getting struck by lightning. One person who was wet survived because the lightning travelled along the outside of their skin instead of going through her body. http://www.struckbylightning.org/

Comment: As referenced in [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/can-you-be-electrocuted-while-taking-a-shower-during-a-thunderstorm/3789#3789) by **tylerl** you can be electrocuted, which can be fatal. As **Tjaart** commented, the current can run mainly through the water on the outside of your body, rather than through your heart (which would kill you immediately), but you would get enough shock that can lead to fatal outcome.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

It happens.

I'm sure there are more examples than just this, but these two examples were on the first page of search results. You don't have to look far.

In 2007
http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/article491125.ece

In 2008
http://www.kcci.com/r/16265120/detail.html

Comment: One links to a store of a shock, not an electrocution. The other is a dead link.